# Variational autoencoder: Does encoder must have the same number of layers as the decoder?

Tags: keras, autoencoder

Does encoder must have the same number of layers as the decoder, in Variational Autoencoder? I got a little better result with the encoder (Dense): 54-10-5-3 and Decoder (Dense): 3-5-10-25-35-45-54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked an excellent question and the answer is no.

Since Aldream has already pointed a few works that use asymmetric architecture, I would like to point out the theoretical work that is related to your question.

I believe the best explanation is from ICLR 2017 conference paper: "Variational Lossy Autoencoder", Xi Chen and et al.

Section 2 is the must-read section. The author links variational autoencoder to bit-back coding and shows that the average code length (which is equivalent to variational lowerbound) always has extra code length from using approximate posterior distribution. **When the decoder of VAE (which is log-datalikelihood p(x|z)) can model the data without the need of q(z|x), VAE will ignore the latent variable!**

It means that if we have a very strong decoder (e.g. the same number of layers as the encoder), then there is a risk that VAE might completely ignore learning q(z|x) by simply set q(z|x) to the prior p(z), hence, keeps the KL loss to 0.

For more details, please read the paper above. The connection of VAE to bit-back coding is elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not uncommon to have asymmetric architectures, e.g. [1, 2, 3, etc.].

1. Tang, Shuai, et al. "Exploring Asymmetric Encoder-Decoder Structure for Context-based Sentence Representation Learning." arXiv preprint arXiv:1710.10380 (2017). [pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10380.pdf)
2. LiNalisnick, Eric, and Padhraic Smyth. "Stick-breaking variational autoencoders." International Conference on Learning Representations (ICLR). 2017. [pdf](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10039928)
3. Nash, Charlie, and Chris KI Williams. "The shape variational autoencoder: A deep generative model of part‐segmented 3D objects." Computer Graphics Forum. Vol. 36. No. 5. 2017. [pdf](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/sgp2017.pdf)